# Merge SQL script files (in order)

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have all my tables, views, triggers in different files (Table1.sql, Table2.sql, View1.sql,...), and I need to combine all my model scripts to create a allinone.sql script (e.g. to a deliverable for deploy). Right now I can combine all using "type" command like this:

```
type *.sql > allinone.sql (or cat in bash)
```

But, as I have referential integrity, I need to stablish the order to merge the files. (otherwise the allinone.sql script will fail by referential integrity)

Do you know any software or method to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disable fkey check before running your script

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

at the end, type

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

to enable your fkey check

Comment: I think that is a "good" solution. It works but then we do not will check the constraints. Do you imagine send a deliverable to a client with a Foreign Key deactivation at the top of the script? I have confident in myself (my script is OK), but when execute the script will be desirable check the restrictions. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL implementation has an *include file* mechanism, you could use that. For Postgres's psql terminal monitor, this can be done using the `\i filename` command:

```
\i create_database.sql
\i create_tables.sql
\i populate_tables.sql
\i create_indexes.sql
\i create_functions.sql
\i create_triggers.sql
\i revoke_and_grant.sql
\i do_some_checks.sql
```

This should all be put into a "all_files.sql" script, and then submitted by `psql a_database <all_files.sql`.
You'll have to manually order the scripts to get the required order of execution, of course.